# Quadratic permutations of $(1,2,\dots{},n)$

Tags: combinatorics, contest-math

Call a permutation $\left(p_1,p_2,\dots,p_n\right)$ of $\left(1,2,\dots{},n\right)$ *quadratic* if there exists a perfect square among $$p_1,\, p_1+p_2,\dots,\, p_1+p_2+\cdots+p_n.$$
Find all natural numbers $n$ such that all the permutations of $(1,2,\dots,n)$ are quadratic.

Comment: May not help much, but there are infinitely many of them.  Just take any $n$ which is both a triangular number and a perfect square (then the final sum is a square).  Do you know any examples not of this form?

Comment: Interesting, though invalid question. For $n = 2$, we already have $2,1$ which is not quadratic. Combined with lulu's comment, I think this question needs some work. Is there a reason behind this question?

Comment: @lulu: Yep! The answer is the set of those $n$ for which $\dfrac{n(n+1)}{2}$ is perfect square

Comment: To clarify my comment (which was poorly phrased):  I meant take any $n$ such that $1+\dots+n$ is a perfect square.  Thus that sum is both a triangular number and a perfect square.

Comment: Is it obvious that this is the entire set?  I was working off that guess but haven't proved it yet.

Comment: Also @Pieter21 (2,1) may not be quadratic but (3,2,1) is. And yes there are infinitely many $n$ but it has a closed form

Comment: @lulu: Induction works! The base case is clear and for $a_{k+1}$ show that if $\dfrac{(k+1)(k+2)}{2}$ is not a square then construct a permutation such that none of the sums can be a perfect square.

Comment: Tried that...but apparently not hard enough.  Thanks.

Comment: n(n+1)/2 being a perfect square only fits n = 0,1?!

Comment: What?  There are infinitely many triangular squares.  The sequence is $\{ 1, 36, 1225, 41616, 1413721, 48024900...\}$.  There's a simple recursion for them (Pell's equation).  http://www.cut-the-knot.org/do_you_know/triSquare.shtml

Comment: @Pieter21  There are infinitely many examples.  See, eg, http://www.cut-the-knot.org/do_you_know/triSquare.shtml

Comment: Can you describe the construction?  I'm not seeing it.

Comment: Sure. Assume that such a sequence exists for $k$. If $\frac{k(k+1)}{2}$ is not a square then take $a_{k+1}=k+1.$ If $\frac{k(k+1)}{2}$ is a square then change $a_k=k$ into $a_k=k+1$ and $a_{k+1}=k.$ This forces $\frac{(k+1)(k+2)}{2}$ to be a square.

Comment: Ok...so what if $k$ is a triangular square.  How do I advance to the next case?

Comment: See OEIS sequence [A001110](https://oeis.org/A001110).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bravo to the commenters. Some really interesting stuff going on there. I will just attempt here to consolidate their thoughts into an answer, because the ideas presented there are haphazard, creative and somewhat disorganized. There is a general statement that can be made which subsumes the reasoning in what I think is an elegant way. See the following lemma.

**Lemma:** For any natural $n > 0$, there exists a permutation $p_1, p_2, \dots, p_n$ of the first $n$ natural numbers such that
**(i)** for all $k < n$ (notice strictness), the term $\sum_{i=1}^kp_i$ is not square, and
**(ii)** if $\sum_{i=1}^np_i$ is square, then $p_n = n$.

**Proof:** By induction on $n$. The base case is trivial, for there are clearly no positive natural numbers less than $1$, and clearly $p_1 = 1$. For the inductive case, I borrow heavily from a comment above of the OP. We simply take the sequence $p_1, p2, \dots, p_n$, and consider two cases:

- If $\sum_{i=1}^np_i$ is a square, call it $s^2$. By part **(ii)** of the inductive hypothesis we have that $p_n = n$. Then for our permutation of size $n+1$, we copy all $p_i$ from the old permutation of length $n$, and simply replace $p_n$ with $n+1$ and set $p_{n+1}$ to $n$. Clearly this gives us condition **(i)** for our new sequence, for all the partial sums up to length $n-1$ are the same as before, and the sum up to $p_n$ is $s^2 + 1$, which is never square. Now we must show that the sum up to $p_{n+1}$ is not square, or else we violate condition **(ii)**. Well, this follows from the fact that no two consecutive triangle numbers are squares, which is evident from the recurrence relation given in the link provided in the comments: [tri-squares](http://www.cut-the-knot.org/do_you_know/triSquare.shtml).
- If $\sum_{i=1}^np_i$ is not a square, then we have it easy. Just take the old permutation and append $p_n = n$ to it. Clearly conditions **(i)** and **(ii)** are now met.

**Corollary:** This lemma immediately gives us that the numbers whose permutations are all quadratic are exactly the triangular square numbers, and no other numbers.

---

**Update:** The OEIS link provided by Robert Israel in his comment gives us the following property for the sequence of square-triangular numbers $a(n)$: "For every $n$, $a(n)$ is the first of three triangular numbers in geometric progression. The third number in the progression is $a(n+1)$." This clearly gives us the property needed in the above proof, which is that there are no consecutive triangular numbers that are also square.

Comment: Thanks!  Couldn't get it to work out, for whatever reason.  Much appreciated.

Comment: My pleasure! I basically just took the comments and flattened them out- grunt work :)